# Display image thumbnails on blade view (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, image, laravel

I have to view image thumbnails on my **view.blade.php** i have directory as as**sets/students/id id is the directory of every student id it will be 1 for st**udent1 and 2 for stident2 mean directory will become as

**assets/students/1**

**assets/students/2**

Every directory have 2 images inside one is with default name and 2nd is thumbnail.png i want to view every thumbnail form each student directory to my view 
my method is as

```
$students = Students::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

**i am getting all paths in method as**

```
$attached = [];

    $destination = config('school.attachment_path.students');
    if(is_dir($destination)) {
        $pix = File::allFiles($destination);
        foreach ($pix as $attachment) {
            $attached[] = pathinfo($attachment);
        }

    }
```

If i do this

```
 dd($attached);
            die;
```

It giving me output as

```
    array:4 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "dirname" => "C:\wamp64\www\achool-app\assets/student/\1"
    "basename" => "org.PNG"
    "extension" => "PNG"
    "filename" => "org"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "dirname" => "C:\wamp64\www\achool-app\assets/student/\1"
    "basename" => "thumbnail.png"
    "extension" => "png"
    "filename" => "thumbnail"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "dirname" => "C:\wamp64\www\achool-app\assets/student/\2"
    "basename" => "Capture.PNG"
    "extension" => "PNG"
    "filename" => "Capture"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "dirname" => "C:\wamp64\www\achool-app\assets/student/\2"
    "basename" => "thumbnail.png"
    "extension" => "png"
    "filename" => "thumbnail"
  ]
]
```

I want to view thumbnail of both directories in my view i try as

```
return view('student-gallery.view')->with(compact('attached' , 'students'));
```

**View**

```
@foreach($attached_files as $attached_file)
<div">
  <img src="{{URL::to('/assets/students/' . $students->id . '/thumbnail.png')}}" alt="" width="50px" height="50px">
 </div>
@endforeach
```

Unfortunately its not working its giving error of **$students->id** as

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id

And not displaying thumbnails

Thanks if any body can help to fix it

Comment: if i enter this in url it gives directory with original and thumbnail in it

Comment: what do you get when you do `dd($students)` in your view ?

Comment: getting student data back including every thing

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. it will show all students thumbmails

```
@foreach ($students as $student) 
<div>
<img src="{{ asset('/assets/students/' . $student->id .'/thumbnail.png') }}" alt="" width="50px" height="50px">
</div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

$students doesn't like be that it having only one record.
You need to do for loop for it to fetch data of each student.

```
@if (! $students->isEmpty()) {  // Also check if students data is coming in collection
     @foreach ($students as $student)
        // echo $student->id;
        @foreach($attached_files as $attached_file)
          <div>
          <img src="{{URL::to('/assets/students/' . $student->id . '/thumbnail.png')}}" alt="" width="50px" height="50px">
          </div>
        @endforeach
     @endforeach
@endif
```

For better understanding, you can try print_r($students).

Comment: where should i try this in my controller method?

Comment: i try this in method its returning available students ids

Comment: You need to use this in view...updated my answer.
still if you getting prob share print_r of $students.

Comment: its working but displaying only one pic form 1st dir

Comment: Have you changed constant thumbnail.png to dynamic image filename ?
Might  be $attached_file['basename'] in place of thumbnail.png based on your data.